# Removing an item from Listview causes all items below it to flash on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

This only happens on Android, I have an animation that sets the height, margin, padding spacing of the StackView in the ViewCell and the Height of the ViewCell to 0. I even added a delay to make sure that the position of lower elements didn't change. And indeed, the elements below the removed element didn't change, but they all just flashed. The same happens when I move that itme to the end of the List. I've had to just hide the element instead of removing it. How can this be overcome? Or is there a way I can create a class that implements an Observable Collection, create a delete method that doesn't trigger the Collection Changed event? Thanks

```
public class ExtendedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool _suppressNotification = false;

    public bool AllowNotifications { get { return _suppressNotification; } }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    public void ActivateNotifications()
    {
        _suppressNotification = false;
    }

    public void DesactivateNotifications()
    {
        _suppressNotification = true;
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        _suppressNotification = true;

        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: @hugo This causes an unhandleded exceptoin when I call remove after I jave called DeactivateNotifications. Sepcifically, at OnPropertyChanged() but not OnCollectionChanged()

Comment: Try to replace OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)); with OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));